# Sqlite unable to open .mbtiles file

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, mbtiles

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and sqlite version 2.8.17 .When I run:

```
sqlite OSM-OpenCPN2-MediEast-20200115-2320.mbtiles
```

from terminal its give me this:

```
Unable to open database "OSM-OpenCPN2-MediEast-20200115-2320.mbtiles": file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I downloaded mbtiles from openseamap.

**Update:**
I could opened the mbtiles as a sqlite database but I am confused how do attract them and make them real map.I am using Qt5/c++ for make an offline map.

Comment: sqlite **2**? Try sqlite **3**, assuming that file is a sqlite database at all. What does `file` say about it?

Comment: MBTiles is a file format for storing map tiles in a single file. It is, technically, a SQLite database.

Comment: I tryed with sqlite3 and its opened.Thank you.

Comment: I can opened the mbtiles but I am not sure how I can attract the maptiles and make them real map